# Let $f$ be a continious function in $\mathbb{R}$ , show that the equation f(x)=0 has at least a solution in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ be a continious function in $\mathbb{R}$ such that : 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=a$$
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x)=b$$

And $ab<0$

Show that the equation f(x)=0 has at least a solution in $\mathbb{R}$

I think we should use the IVT in that kind of questions .

We have $ab<0$ so we can say that $a>0$ and $b<0$ for example then just using a graph we could see that there is at least a point where $f(x)=0$

But i don't see how to demontrate it mathematically

Comment: Well, you just have to use the IVT, just as you said. What point is bothering you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can say the following: Without loss of generality $a>0,b<0$.

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a$ means that given $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists some $r>0$ such that $|f(x)-a| < \epsilon$ whenever $x > r$. Now, just take $\epsilon = \frac{a}{2}$, and we get that there exists some $r>0$ such that $|f(x)-a| < \frac{a}{2} $ whenever $ x > r$, so $x > r \implies f(x) > \frac{a}{2} > 0$.

For the other side,$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = b$ means that given $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists some $s<0$ such that $|f(x)-b| < \epsilon$ whenever $x < s$. Now, just take $\epsilon = \frac{b}{2}$, and we get that there exists some $s<0$ such that $|f(x)-b| < \frac{b}{2} $ whenever $ x < s$, so $x < s \implies f(x) < \frac{b}{2} < 0$.

Now, by what we have written, $f(2s) < 0$ as $2s < s$, and $f(2r) > 0$ as $r<2r$. Using intermediate value theorem, between $2s$ and $2r$ there exists a value $n$ such that $f(n)=0$.

Comment: I feel as though this is slightly overkill.

Comment: Isn't the point of this question to prove a part of the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @Vincent The IVT is well known, it's proof is separate from an application of this kind. The reason why the overkill is required, is because we are talking limits and not individual values here. It's not enough to say that the value at infinity is negative and the value at negative infinity is positive, so IVT can be applied. It applies for two real points, which have to be produced carefully using the logic I applied above.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Jam You are welcome.

Comment: Why exactly you took 2r and 2s ?

Comment: I could have taken anything smaller than $s$ and greater than $r$ to serve my purpose, for example $s-1$ instead of $2s$ and $r+1$ instead of $2r$ would have done the trick.

Comment: In reality i didn't get the trick ! How could one choose which $r$ and $s$ he wants ?

Comment: By the definition of limit, $r$ and $s$ exist satisfying the constraints I imposed. They can't be chosen. However, once $r$ and $s$ are fixed, then because we showed that for $x > r$ ,$f(x) >0$ and for $x < s$, $f(x) < 0$, then *anything greater than $r$* and *anything smaller than $s$* can  be chosen as the candidate points for applying IVT.